# How should I request for comment cleanup on migrated questions?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

Going through the list of [recently migrated questions](https://superuser.com/tools?s=1&tab=migrated&daterange=) (10k), some of these really need some editing or other moderation.

What you see quite often on those questions [are comments like](https://superuser.com/q/349684/48078):

> - not seeing how this is a ServerFault question. – *ceejayoz* 1 hour ago
> - Which forum should I move this to? StackOverflow? – *Mark Lutton* 1 hour ago
> - It has even less to do with StackOverflow. – *ceejayoz* 41 mins ago

Now that the question is migrated, they don't serve any purpose and distract from the actual problem.

**Should I flag for moderator attention to have those deleted?**

If so, how should I do it?

- A comment flag, specifying the "Other…" option, asking for comment cleanup?
- A normal flag on the question itself, with the same reason as above?
- A flag on each individual comment using the "Obsolete" flag reason?

Comment: Is posting the comments in question into the mod chat a bad idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Flag each one as obsolete: not a great solution. Because of how mod flags are shown it wouldn't be *too* annoying for the moderators if they're all on the same post, but it's a waste of your time
2. Flag the first one with a custom message asking for all irrelevant ones to be removed. This is better, because you only have to flag once.
3. Flag the post itself, and leave a custom flag message asking for comment cleanup. If it's minor cleanup of irrelevant comments on a duplicate post, this isn't the best option, but if you want some nasty or harmful comments removed sooner than later, this is a better choice since it'll show up higher in the flag quee

So for unnecessary comments about migration, flag the first comment and ask for the rest to be removed. For harmful comments, flag the post.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect situation for using the "obsolete" comment flag category.

Comment: See my edits -- wouldn't that be annoying and time-consuming to flag each comment individually?