# Should I flag comments left over after migration?

Tags: discussion, migration, comments, flagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I request for comment cleanup on migrated questions?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3615/how-should-i-request-for-comment-cleanup-on-migrated-questions)

When a question is migrated from another site, I often see comments left over like "*this site is for programming questions, your post will be migrated soon*" (from Stack Overflow) or "*This site is for IT professionals*" (from Server Fault).  Should I flag these comments as obsolete?

Comment: I didn't quite see such a question in the automatic search...